Pyqtgraph Flask threading issue
I would like to ask whether it is possible to use Pyqtgraph in flask for plotting graphs.
My simplified code:
pg_layout = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(
        title=title,
        size=(2880, 960)
    )
p1 = pg_layout.addPlot(row = 0, col = 0)
    p1.plot(df["C"], pen=pg.mkPen('g'))
.
.
.
pyqtgraph.exporters.ImageExporter(pg_layout.sceneObj).export(tmpfile)

Then I will read the exported png file and use it in my Flask response in URI format.
The current issue is that PyQT5 backend and QApplication is not designed to work with multiple threads.
Basically, the first time I receive a request from Flask, the QApplication is started in that Flask thread. Which works fine.
But then the second time i get a request, it will be a new thread, and the PyQT5 will spam me with

QBasicTimer::start: QBasicTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread
QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread
in the console.

How may I implement PyQTGraph to work with Flask event-based multithreading? Thanks!

You must ensure that the function is called within the same thread of the application, which can only be correctly achieved using signals. You could create a QObject subclass with a custom signal and a function that actually creates the pyqtgraph objects, connect the signal to that function, and emit the signal when required from flask. It should be enough to ensure that the function is called in the QObject's thread, but you can even enforce it by using connect() with the Qt.QueuedConnection argument following the connected slot.
